# How to import a class with constants in Jenkins Pipeline?

Tags: class, jenkins, groovy, import, load

I have some class with only constants without any methods in `/src/ru/foo/bar/Const.groovy`

```
package ru.foo.bar

class Const {
    public static final String BITBUCKET_LOGIN = "DEV_LOGIN"
    public static final String BITBUCKET_PASS = "DEV_PASS"
{
```

In Jenkins pipeline i use it like this:

```
import ru.foo.bar.Const

pipeline {
    stages {
        stage {
            script {
                println("${Const.BITBUCKET_LOGIN}")
                doSomeThingWith(PASS: "${Const.BITBUCKET_PASS}")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and everything works perfectly!

Now I need to make different files for different environments and load it dynamically inside the pipeline, but so that nothing else changes in the pipeline.

I try to comment `//import ru.foo.bar.Const`
and add to pipeline something like that

```
sh 'cp environments/${Stand}/Const.groovy jenkins/Const.groovy'
def Const = load 'jenkins/Const.groovy'
println("${Const.BITBUCKET_LOGIN}")
doSomeThingWith(PASS: "${Const.BITBUCKET_PASS}")
```

I also tried just

```
load 'jenkins/Const.groovy'
```

But that doesn't work either as well as other ideas from Google.

How can I load my class in the pipeline correctly so that I can access constants like `${Const.SOMEVARIABLE}` ?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem on my own.

/src/ru/foo/bar/Const.groovy:

```
class Const {
    public static final String BITBUCKET_LOGIN = "DEV_LOGIN"
    public static final String BITBUCKET_PASS = "DEV_PASS"
{
return new Const()
```

and in pipeline use like:

```
sh 'cp environments/${Stand}/Const.groovy jenkins/Const.groovy'
Const = load 'jenkins/Const.groovy'
println("${Const.BITBUCKET_LOGIN}")
doSomeThingWith(PASS: "${Const.BITBUCKET_PASS}")
```

and everything works perfectly!