# Error in import a class with constants in Jenkins Pipeline

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I'm following the method in [How to import a class with constants in Jenkins Pipeline?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63030857/how-to-import-a-class-with-constants-in-jenkins-pipeline)

I use the similar code but got the error below:

```
WorkflowScript: 5: unable to resolve class ru.foo.bar.Const
 @ line 5, column 1.
   import ru.foo.bar.Const
   ^

1 error

    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.failIfErrors(ErrorCollector.java:310)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToSourceUnits(CompilationUnit.java:958)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:605)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:554)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.doParseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:298)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:268)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parseClass(GroovyShell.java:688)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parse(GroovyShell.java:700)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsGroovyShell.doParse(CpsGroovyShell.java:133)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsGroovyShell.reparse(CpsGroovyShell.java:126)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsFlowExecution.parseScript(CpsFlowExecution.java:561)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsFlowExecution.start(CpsFlowExecution.java:522)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowRun.run(WorkflowRun.java:320)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:429)
```

Code as below:

src/ru/foo/bar/Const.groovy

```
package ru.foo.bar

class Const {
    public static final String BITBUCKET_LOGIN = "DEV_LOGIN"
    public static final String BITBUCKET_PASS = "DEV_PASS"
}
return new Const()
```

```
import ru.foo.bar.Const

pipeline {
  stages {
    stage('init') {
      steps {
        script {
          println("${Const.BITBUCKET_LOGIN}")
        }
      }

    } /* 'ais refstack parallel builds' */
}
```

Anything not correct in my usage?

Answer (score 0):

Actually you need to make that class visible to your `Jenkinsfile`. From my understanding just `import` is not enough.

Check the relevant jenkins [documentation](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/#loading-libraries-dynamically):

> Using classes from the src/ directory is also possible, but trickier. Whereas the @Library annotation prepares the “classpath” of the script prior to compilation, by the time a library step is encountered the script has already been compiled. Therefore you cannot import or otherwise “statically” refer to types from the library.

> However you may use library classes dynamically (without type checking), accessing them by fully-qualified name from the return value of the library step. static methods can be invoked using a Java-like syntax:

`library('my-shared-library').com.mycorp.pipeline.Utils.someStaticMethod()`

> You can also access static fields, and call constructors as if they were static methods named new:

```
def useSomeLib(helper) { // dynamic: cannot declare as Helper
    helper.prepare()
    return helper.count()
}

def lib = library('my-shared-library').com.mycorp.pipeline // preselect the package

echo useSomeLib(lib.Helper.new(lib.Constants.SOME_TEXT))
```

**But** your snippet indicates that you're handling credentials. You should heavily consider to handle them [properly](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/jenkinsfile/#handling-credentials).

```
    environment {
        BITBUCKET = credentials('bitbucket')
    }
```